# EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get text from textBox in editItemTemplate and nothing seems to work. I have tried to use FindControl in my RowUpdating and still no luck. I am working in c#. Any good walk thoughs on how to get this to work?

Comment: Do you want to get it in code-behind or in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

you need to find control like this, based on the row index of your  gridview.

```
 protected void gvMemberClassificationDetail_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField  hdMemberCode = this.gvMemberClassificationDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hidID") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField;
    DropDownList status = this.gvMemberClassificationDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlClassificationStatus") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList;
    TextBox Comments = this.gvMemberClassificationDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRemarks") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;
    ObjectDataSource4.UpdateParameters["memberCode"].DefaultValue = hdMemberCode.Value;
    ObjectDataSource4.UpdateParameters["status"].DefaultValue = status.SelectedValue;
    ObjectDataSource4.UpdateParameters["comments"].DefaultValue = Comments.Text;
}
```